# Doctrine Event - sql query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Welcome,

I have Listener and method postPersist(). I need the sql code to with "$em->persist()". My example:

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
  $em = $args->getEntityManager();
  //..
  $em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister($name);


}
```

I see:
private 'insertSql' => string 'INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' (length=108) But I don't have access.

Why do I need sql code? Because I have to send sql to the table without Entity.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement with `postPersist` in a bit details please.
If you are using `LifecycleEventArgs`, you don't need to deal with custom query. Doctrine can handle itself.

Comment: I have to make copies of the model to another table. When I have "previous query" I can change name the tables and send record.

Comment: Have you configured that `another table` as another ORM Entity in your application? If so, You can still copy those data with change of attribute value as per your requirement.

Comment: `$em->persist()` only tells Doctrine that it had to manage this entity. Id doesn't write on DB. So there is no SQL equivalent to `$em->persist()`.

Comment: @Jeet: "Another Table" is not model entity. This table isn't mapping in model.

Comment: @AlFonce:  I know, but in the Persister I see the query... I would like this query

Comment: @viko, why don't you prepare your own query and change values after getting them from old entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
  $em = $args->getEntityManager();
  $entity = $args->getObject();
  $originalEntityData = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($entity);
}
```

getOriginalEntityData() returns array with fields name and value. But when record is update, this method doesn't return ID object. Date and DateTime are objects.

When I have this data(fields and values object), I can send a record using the PDO. Maybe I should use model, but stores the state of the object... (versionable) and writes it in DB.